# using variable from function in method C#

Tags: c#, excel, function, windows-forms-designer

I made a function to open Excel, open a workbook and then set a certain worksheet as active (depending on user input). The function...

```
public void openExcel()
    {
        var excelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();   
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProgramForMom\ProgramForMom\bin\Debug\Excel Files\" + frm2.year.Text + " Expenses";
        Workbook wb = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);    
        wb.Activate(); 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[frm2.month.Text];
        ws.Activate(); 
    }
```

I have another method in which I would like to select a range on the worksheet...

```
var cellValue = ws.Range["A10"].Value2;
```

I get the following error:

> "The name 'ws' does not exist in the current context"

I tried looking at this msdn page but had difficulty understanding it (I am new to programming) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

I have about 5 different methods (based on when the user clicks different buttons in windows forms) and in each method I want to open excel the same way, but then select different ranges. Is there any way of doing this besides rewriting it 5 times?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify the file name to `string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"Excel Files\" + frm2.year.Text + " Expenses");`

Comment: @Slai Thanks! I wanted to find a way to use it on different computers and your suggestion is a lot better than mine. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use your existing method. Just let it return the opened Worksheet:

```
public Worksheet openExcel()
{
    var excelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();   
    string fileName = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProgramForMom\ProgramForMom\bin\Debug\Excel Files\" + frm2.year.Text + " Expenses";
    Workbook wb = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);    
    wb.Activate(); 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[frm2.month.Text];
    ws.Activate(); 
    return ws; // return the activated Worksheet
}
```

You can then use the reference to `ws` in your other methods:

```
public void SomeMainMethod()
{
    // open the worksheet
    Worksheet ws = openExcel();

    // and use it anywhere
    // invoke your other method(s) and provide the reference to 'ws'
    YourOtherMethod(ws); 
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I spent like 2 hours searching for that. Thanks that makes it really, really simple and easy!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. If I wanted to return both the workbook and the worksheet, do you know how I would do that? Maybe a tuple would work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable from one function in another function.

You declared the `ws` variable on the `openExcel` function so you can use it there, if you want to use it in another function you have to declare if again in the second function.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[frm2.month.Text];
var cellValue = ws.Range["A10"].Value2;
```

Or you can decalre the `ws` as a global variable, within the class but outside the functions and then it will be accessible and recognized in all the functions on this class.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I have a question if you don't mind. I have about 5 different methods (based on when the user clicks different buttons in windows forms) and in each method I want to open excel the same way, but then select different ranges. Is there any way of doing this besides rewriting it 5 times?

Comment: @Michael yes, create a method and place in it the common logic. Then call it in the 5 methods and return from it the Range `ws`.. Instead of `public void`, use `public Range` or whatever the type is.